# How to get filename based on the event object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Imagine that an HTML file `page1.html` has a script tag for `base.js`. In `base.js` (i.e. external JavaScript file), I assign onclick listener to a `button` that exists in `page1.html`. Furthermore, `base.js` is included in `script` tags across `page1.html`, `page2.html`, etc., and each `button` in each `page*?*.html` has the same onclick listener assigned to it.

Now, I need to somehow know in the `base.js` which HTML file invoked the onclick listener, in other words, in which `page*?*.html` webpage the method was fired. Ideally, I would get the filename of that `page*?*.html`, where *?* could be 1, 2, 3, etc. Is there a way to accomplish that? The code should look like this...

```
// fires up when a button in 'page*?*.html' is clicked
function myOnClickEventHandler(e) {
    // the file where myOnClickEventHandler originated from is:
    var filename = e.???????
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var filename = location.href.match(/([^\/]*?)$/)[1];`

on this page, it's "how-to-get-filename-based-on-the-event-object-in-javascript"

Comment: Perfect answer; I must apologize for such an obvious question. I thought it would be more involved because of the onlick event in the external JS file...